# SSIS, Oracle connection, and configuration files

Tags: xml, oracle, ssis

I have an SSIS package (**Archive.dtsx**) and a configuration file (**ArchiveConfig.dtsConfig**). The package uses an Oracle connection which, in the designer, works without any issues. However, once deployed and executed from command line, the package fails to validate the Oracle connection. Everything else in the package works perfectly fine, the MS SQL Data Flows function fine, it's the Oracle Data Flows that are causing the problem and I believe it has something to do with the configuration file.

The command I'm using:

```
dtexec /f "g:\SSIS\Archive.dtsx" /conf "g:\SSIS\ArchiveConfig.dtsConfig" /set "\Package.Variables[User::date].Value";"MAY_2004"
```

And the configuration code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTSConfiguration>
    <DTSConfigurationHeading>
        <DTSConfigurationFileInfo 
            GeneratedDate="5/2/2012 1:25:21 PM" 
            GeneratedFromPackageID="{AA679926-1E5C-42ED-B805-450A3E7AE555}" 
            GeneratedFromPackageName="Archive" 
            GeneratedBy="davenport"/>
    </DTSConfigurationHeading>
    <Configuration ValueType="String" Path="\Package.Connections[Oracle].Properties[ConnectionString]" ConfiguredType="Property">
        <ConfiguredValue>
            Data Source=ORACLE;User ID=userName;Persist Security Info=True;Unicode=True;
        </ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ValueType="String" Path="\Package.Connections[Oracle].Properties[Password]" ConfiguredType="Property">
        <ConfiguredValue>
            password
        </ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ValueType="String" Path="\Package.Connections[Oracle].Properties[ServerName]" ConfiguredType="Property">
        <ConfiguredValue>
            ORACLE
        </ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ValueType="String" Path="\Package.Connections[Oracle].Properties[UserName]" ConfiguredType="Property">
        <ConfiguredValue>
            userName
        </ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
</DTSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to modify Config file .

Please check the below steps.

Before deploying  the package . you should have Oracle Client into your System . and  you have to open .TNS file from below location After installation :

C:\Oracle\product\11.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin

and After that u have to copy Source System  TNS File from Same location and update the details in your System TNS File with Credential .

> > u can Test Connection using net manager if the connection is Successes then you are on right path .

Answer (score 1):

you need to have the oracle client installed and edit the `tnsnames.ora` file

Here is an example:

```
ORACLE=
  (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = your_host)(PORT = your_port)))
  (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = your_service_name)
  )
)
```